# Not able to show map marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add map marker in my map. I have a fragment in which I want to show map marker. I have added 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1' in my app's gradle. But I an having error i.e.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

// xml file code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp176"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

// code for map

```
public class KantorenOfficeDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

      GoogleMap googleMap;


      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kantoren_office_details, container, false);
       setUpMapIfNeeded();
       return v;
        }

       private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
             SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
             mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
             if (googleMap != null) {
                 setUpMap();
             }
        }
    }

   private void setUpMap() {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7253, 75.8655)).title("Indore"));    // here is marker Adding code
          }

    }
```

Comment: have you created the project on google developer console?

Comment: and grabbed google_api_key?

Comment: No, I have not. But it is showing me  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: my dear you need to create the project on google developers console and then get the google_api_key from here which will help you to inflate the map on your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you are not initialize you `googleMap` object.

MapFragment Initialize must like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            mapFragment= (MyMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        else
            mapFragment= (MyMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and then import the callback method

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
}
```

call this `setUpMap` in inside callback method

```
 if (googleMap != null) {
       setUpMap();
   }
```

Your `OnMapReady` Must be like

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
       if (googleMap != null) {
           setUpMap();
       }
    }
```

Hope it will help you